# Modify PayPal API invoice detail payment terms

Tags: api, paypal

I am trying to send an invoice through the sandbox using PayPal API.  I can successfully send and create and invoice using sample data.  But I do not want it to be Net_10.  I want Due On Receipt. I can not find any documentation giving the exact way to write it.  I have tried Upon_Receipt, DueUponReceipt, and On_Receipt.  Want to change term_type and remove due_date.

```
"payment_term": {
      "term_type": "NET_10",
      "due_date": "2018-11-22"
    },
```

`````
  +"name": "INVALID_REQUEST"
  +"message": "Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema."
  +"debug_id": "dd55a145fdb2f"
  +"details": array:1 [▼
    0 => {#1471 ▼
      +"field": "detail/payment_term/term_type"
      +"location": "body"
      +"description": "Cannot construct instance of `com.paypal.invoicing.v2.model.PaymentTerm$TermType`, problem: On_Receipt at line:10, column:20" ````
`````

Answer (score 0):

Valid values for "term_type" are:

- "DUE_ON_RECEIPT"
- "DUE_ON_DATE_SPECIFIED"
- "NET_10"
- "NET_15"
- "NET_30"
- "NET_45"
- "NET_60"
- "NET_90"
- "NO_DUE_DATE"

This was taken from the code posted in [a question asked on the PayPal Community forum](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Business-Tools-Archives/Update-status-invoice-sdk/m-p/2063711). I do not know if this is an exhaustive list.